# Service or not for persistent data

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application that keeps some complex data in memory between activities.

As for now I use a `Singleton` class that use `SharedPreferences` in getters and setters.

**What I want**: As long as my application is live and showing in the recent apps, I want a class to never get released or find a way to achieve this another way without consequences.

- So I was wondering, is a better way available to me?
- Would a Service be better?
- If so, should I start and/or bind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go with a service, you wouldn't bind it as unbinding could cause it to stop.

You could create a static object and create it in a custom Application class. So for as long as your application is alive the object is held by a strong reference.

Or a combination, use a singleton class but let the application class store the reference to prevent garbagecollection(GC)

after chat:

a service running in its own process should be the most persistent thing you could build. However you need to communicate with the service via AIDL, a cross-process bridge, which draws performance if the communication is high-speed.

Comment: The second point, however, does not work (as I tried it with a `public static` variable).

Comment: check out the 2nd answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables

Comment: As I said in my second comment: I did and I still do. But it is not persistent.

Comment: Could you explain the circumstances under which your objects dissapear ?

Comment: but when does it disappear ?

Comment: by the GC: so after some time, or when I start a lot of applications

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20330/discussion-between-shkschneider-and-nikkyd)